# Form posting large file fails with Zend framework

Tags: php, forms, post, zend-framework, file-upload

I am trying to make a form where users upload a large file. However, the form stops to work when the file is bigger than 1.5Gb. My requirement is 8Gb max. For testing purposes I have been using a 2Gb file.

I have a form that accepts an input file.

```
<form id="createUpdateTrial" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
    <input type="file" name="buildfile" id="buildfile"/>
</form>
```

Then in zend framework 1.12, I try to receive the file.

```
//Validation
        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
        
        if ($upload->isUploaded()) {
            
            $upload->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' => 1, 'max' => 1));
            $upload->addValidator('Size', false,  8589934592); //8GB in bytes

            $upload->setDestination("uploads/");

            if (!$upload->isValid()) {

                $errorMessages = $upload->getMessages();
                if (count($errorMessages) > 0)
                {
                    $errorSuffix = ": " . print_r($upload->getMessages(), true);
                }
                else
                    $errorSuffix = "";

                throw new Exception("File doesn't pass validation" . $errorSuffix);
            }

            try {  
               $upload->receive();
            }
            catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
                
                throw new Exception('Bad file data: '.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

After the form finishes uploading the file, when the above code is ran, the Zend_File_Transfer object says the upload is invalid with the following messages:

> File doesn't pass validation: Array\n(\n    [fileCountTooFew] => Too few files, minimum '1' are expected but '0' are given\n    [fileUploadErrorCantWrite] => File 'buildfile' can't be written\n)

In my php config file, I have the following settings:

> max_input_time = 3600
>
> post_max_size = 8G
>
> upload_max_filesize = 8G

I can confirm that there is more than enough space on the server to hold the uploaded file. The server is running PHP 5.6.16

If someone has any ideas as to why this doesn't work with larger files, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$upload->isUploaded()` to `$upload->isUploaded('buildfile')` & `$upload->isUploaded()` to `$upload->isUploaded('buildfile')`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue :( Still the same failure. Thanks for the reply though